# Can sqrtsd in inline assembler be faster than sqrt()?

Tags: c++, inline-assembly, clock

I am creating a testing utility that requires high usage of sqrt() function. After digging in possible optimisations, I have decided to try inline assembler in C++. The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

volatile double normalSqrt(double a){
    double b = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++){
        b = sqrt(a);
    }
    return b;
}

volatile double asmSqrt(double a){
    double b = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++){
        asm volatile(
            "movq %1, %%xmm0 \n"
            "sqrtsd %%xmm0, %%xmm1 \n"
            "movq %%xmm1, %0 \n"
            : "=r"(b)
            : "g"(a)
            : "xmm0", "xmm1", "memory"
        );
    }
    return b;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    double a = atoi(argv[1]);
    double c;
    std::clock_t start;
    double duration;

    start = std::clock();

    c = asmSqrt(a);

    duration = std::clock() - start;

    cout << "asm sqrt: " << c << endl;
    cout << duration << " clocks" <<endl;
    cout << "Start: " << start << " end: " << start + duration << endl;

    start = std::clock();

    c = normalSqrt(a);
    duration = std::clock() - start;

    cout << endl << "builtin sqrt: " << c << endl;
    cout << duration << " clocks" << endl;
    cout << "Start: " << start << " end: " << start + duration << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling this code using this script that sets number of iterations, starts profiling, and opens profiling output in VIM:

```
#!/bin/bash

DEFAULT_ITERATIONS=1000000

if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "Setting ITERATIONS to $1"
    DEFAULT_ITERATIONS=$1
else
    echo "Using default value: $DEFAULT_ITERATIONS"
fi

rm -rf asd

g++ -msse4 -std=c++11 -O0 -ggdb -pg -DITERATIONS=$DEFAULT_ITERATIONS test.cpp -o asd

./asd 16
gprof asd gmon.out > output.txt
vim -O output.txt
true
```

The output is:

```
Using default value: 1000000
asm sqrt: 4
3802 clocks
Start: 1532 end: 5334

builtin sqrt: 4
5501 clocks
Start: 5402 end: 10903
```

The question is why the `sqrtsd` instruction takes only 3802 clocks, to count square root of 16, and `sqrt()` takes 5501 clocks? 
Does it have something to do with HW implementation of certain instructions? Thank you.

CPU:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             AuthenticAMD
CPU family:            21
Model:                 48
Model name:            AMD A8-7600 Radeon R7, 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               3100.000
CPU max MHz:           3100,0000
CPU min MHz:           1400,0000
BogoMIPS:              6188.43
Virtualization:        AMD-V
L1d cache:             16K
L1i cache:             96K
L2 cache:              2048K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

Comment: Why *wouldn't* a dedicated CPU instruction be faster than a software implementation?

Comment: Why does `normalSqrt` do it `ITERATIONS` times in a loop (and `asmSqrt` only does it once)?

Comment: `asmSqrt` compute one root while `normalSqrt`compute `ITERATIONS` roots... Maybe there is a problem here?

Comment: Thanks for notice, I modified the program, however, it still is faster to use sqrtsd instead of sqrt(). Shouldn't sqrt() use instructions built in HW as well?

Comment: Now are you sure your `asm` solution is giving you the same results and percision that `sqrt` does?  Also does your version handle all of the cases `sqrt` does?

Comment: Your test is flawed, The compiler knows the input and may optimize that away.

Comment: @Dieter Lücking How can the compiler know the input? Input is passed down as an argument + I made all functions volatile and put -O0 in the argument of the compiler. AFAIK it shouldn't make any optimisations.

Comment: ... the number of iterations (usually fine) and the fact the input value is not changeing

Comment: "put -O0 in the argument of the compiler." -- benchmarks compiled without optimizations are meaningless. Use -O2 or -O3.

Comment: @Pete Becker With O2 or O3 the number of clocks doubled for both versions of sqrt. I don't know why. I will have to disassemble it, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating point arithmetic has to take into consideration rounding. Most C/C++ compilers adopt IEEE 754, so they have an "ideal" algorithm to perform operations such as square root. They are then free to optimize, but they must return *the same result down to the last decimal, in all cases*. So their freedom to optimize is not complete, in fact it is severely constrained.

Your algorithm probably is off by a digit or two part of the time. Which could be completely negligible for some users, but could also cause nasty bugs for some others, so it's not allowed by default.

If you care more for speed than standard compliance, try poking around with the options of your compiler. For instance in GCC the first I'd try is `-funsafe-math-optimizations`, which should enable optimizations disregarding strict standard compliance. Once you tweak it enough, you should come closer to and possibly pass your handmade implementation's speed.

Comment: Actually C++ itself doesn't adopt IEEE754, but rather compilers choose to or not.  The rest of the answer is good though.

Comment: Using `sqrtsd` is not an algorithm that can ever be wrong. It's even correctly rounded.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the other problems, it will still be the case that `sqrt()` is a bit slower than `sqrtsd`, unless compiled with specific flags.

`sqrt()` has to potentially set `errno`, it has to check whether it's in that case. It will still boil down to the native square root instruction on any reasonable compiler, but it will have a little overhead. Not a lot of overhead like your flaws test showed, but still some.

You can see that in action [here](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g490,options:'-O3',source:'%23include+%3Cmath.h%3E%0A%0Ausing+namespace+std%3B%0A%0Adouble+test(double+x)%0A%7B%0A++++return+sqrt(x)%3B%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3).

Some compile flags suppress this test. For example for GCC, `fno-math-errno` and `ffinite-math-only`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you please share those other problems with me so I could improve?

Comment: @JirkaZahradnik the way you use the results of the square root in the first loop doesn't guarantee that more than 1 square root happens. It has to happen once, but the rest are redundant, and the compiler can remove them. GCC (without cheats enabled) does make a loop, but it precomputes the square root, thus making the loop run much faster than intended. Well, that's not what you observed, but it's clearly a deficiency.